# ¿Cómo puedo animar la barra de navegación cuando haga scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

quisiera hacer el efecto que tiene la página de [Uber Eats](https://www.ubereats.com/es) en su barra de navegación cuando hago scroll. He realizado este codigo que funciona cuando hago scroll hacia abajo, pero cuando vuelvo al punto inicial donde estaba no vuelve la barra a su estado original. Cómo podría hacerlo?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-container">
   <nav>
      <--contenido de la nav-->
   </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-container{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0rem 2.5rem;
    z-index: 1;

    nav{
       //estilo del contenido de la nav
    }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const navAnimations = () =>{
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-container');

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
            nav.style.background = ('white');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

la manera mas fácil de hace es utilizar JavaScript
utilizando la propiedad Window.scroll()

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

el navegado detecta la posición de navegador en numero y cambia la etiqueta class cuando se hace el cambio

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  console.log(y);
  if(y>30){
    var d = document.getElementById("color-3"); 
   // d.setAttribute("style","background-color: rgba(125,55,55)");
    d.className ="ss"
  }else{
    var s = document.getElementById("color-3"); 
    s.className ="sa"
    //s.setAttribute("style","background-color: rgba(125,155,55)");

  }
};
```

```css
.contenido-1{
height:500px
}
.contenido-2{
height:500px
}
estilo-menu{

background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
   float: left;
 }
 .ss{
 background-color: rgba(34,234,30);
 }

.sa{
 background-color: rgba(234,134,30);
 }
```

```html
<div class="nav-container" id="estilo-menu">
   <nav class="estilo-menu">
   Menu
   </nav>
   <p class="contenido-1" id="color-3" >ssss<br>sssssss
   <br>sss
   </p>
   <p class="contenido-2" id="color-4">dddddd</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Eso se puede hacer solamente con **CSS** usando `position: sticky;` de la siguiente manera:

```
.nav-container {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
```

**Importante**.
Si el contenedor padre de `.nav-container`, que debe ser el `body`, entonces funcionará muy bien. Esté donde esté (siempre y cuando dentro de `body`), se quedará fijo `top: 0` al hacer scroll.